# Ajaxswing (converting Java desktop application to web application)- ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to convert a desktop application in Java to web using AjaxSwing. However, I am receiving this error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
```

So my question on the .properties file, how should the classpath be defined? The reason is that I added the specific library in the application CLASSPATH via the Application Properties tab of the Application Wizard. However no luck. Any suggestions?

Btw, I do not get this error when the application is being used as a desktop application.